# Terminology on "Compact Subset"

Tags: general-topology, terminology, compactness

Let's say that $U\subset X=\mathbb{R}^n$ is open. If someone says that $K$ is a compact subset of $U$, what exactly does this mean? Does it mean that $K$ has compact relative closure in $U$ ($\bar{K}\cap U$ is compact)? That it's just a subset of $U$ and compact in $X$? It could mean relatively (as in relative topology), but if $K\subset U\subset X$ and $K$ is compact in $U$, is it not also compact in $X$ (and vice-versa)?

Comment: Compactness is an intrinsic notion.

Comment: @LázaroAlbuquerque I understand the notion of compactness, the question was on terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We say that a subset $K$ of a topological space $X$ is compact it is is compact with respect to the subspace topology. Note that if $K\subset Y\subset X$ and if we endow $Y$ with the subspace topology, then the topology of $Y$ and the topology of $X$ induce the same topologies on $K$ (that is, the subspace topology is the same in both cases). So, $K$ is a compact subset of $Y$ if and only if it is a compact subset of $X$.

But $K$ being a compact subset of $X$ does *not* meant that $K$ is relatively compact. What this means (or is equivalent to) is that $\overline K$ is a compact subset of $X$. When $X=\Bbb R^n$ endowed with its usual topology, this is the same thing as asserting that $K$ is bounded.

Comment: Right, but if one makes no mention of endowing any topology to the subset $U$ (you called it $Y$), then do we take it to mean compact relative closure or do we just assume that it has the subspace topology? I agree that if we specifically call $Y$ a subspace, then the meaning is evident.

Comment: If $U$ is just a set, then I think that asserting that $K$ is a compact subset of $U$ is either meaningless, or that it means that it is a compact subset of $X$ which happens to be a subset of $U$.

Comment: Ah, this is what I figured but feared. I saw this terminology for a set which I could not see as compact but as relatively compact, so I was hoping that the language ambiguity would save me. Thanks, will accept when I am allowed to.